# Embedding videos

Tags: java, android

I am using a simple video view which loads an online video from URL
few videos work but not all videos . does android supports certain types of videos if so is there a way to support all formats ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that, as a developer, you can really only rely on support for formats in Google's stock codec and file type list, which is here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html

It's not all that extensive and, in practice, device vendors usually add additional capabilities. If you're writing something to run on multiple devices, you'd probably have to assume the worse, for maximum compatibility.